# Intercepting a submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of fields that are either filled (inputs) or selected (dropdowns) that working together to create a new page.

I'm attempting to validate the entries and prevent the page creation if anything is wrong with the inputs. No form is being used.
The problem is the `$("#netsubmit").submit(function( event ))` never gets run when the submit is clicked. No errors are thrown, no indication why its not processing.

My html for the input is:

```
<input id="netsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="newNet()"
    title="Submit The New Net">
```

My JQuery javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#netsubmit").submit(function( event ) {
       alert("in it");
        var callentered = $("#callsign").val();
        if (callentered == "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Please enter a call sign first.");
            $("#callsign").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Uh.  You're trying to `.submit()` an input element.  Generally only applicable to forms (The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to <form> elements)

Comment: forms submit, not inputs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.submit()` can only be used with `<form>` elements, as stated in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> It can only be attached to `<form>`elements.

If you do not want to use the form tag, you can switch to using `.click()` instead, like so:

```
$("#netsubmit").click(function(event) {
    alert("in it");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It is likely not working because as you said you aren't using a form element. From the [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to form elements

You could use the function specified by your onclick event `onClick="newNet()"` to validate the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for submit on MDN it explicitly says

> The submit event is fired when a form is submitted.
>
> Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or
>   submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

if you do

```
<form id="myform">
<input id="netsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="newNet()"  title="Submit The New Net">
  </form>
```

and then change the code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myform").submit(function( event ) {
               alert("in it");
                    var callentered = $("#callsign").val();
                        if (callentered == "") {
                            event.preventDefault();
                                alert("Please enter a call sign first.");
                                    $("#callsign").focus();
                        }
            });
  });
```

it works fine